# adb command's equivalent version in java?

Tags: java, android, shell, runtime, adb

I am able to execute an adb shell command of type from the terminal:

`./adb shell 'sh -c "param1 param2 param3 param4"'`

However, when I am trying to run this inside android app using `Runtime.exec` 
the above command gets broken down into different params of the form

`[adb, shell, 'sh, -c, "param1, param2, param3, param4"]`

However, that is a single input param when ran from shell.
How to run this inside the app?

note: param is a kind of path e.g. `/a/b/c/`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20984306/1778421

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11137131/1778421

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid funkyness with how your strings are split, it's usually safer to just use the [multi-paramter version of Runtime.exec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String:A-):

```
System.getRuntime().exec("adb", "shell", "sh -c \"param1 param2 param3 param4\"");
```

Note that in this specific call you've got 2 arguments to the `adb` executable. `shell` and the whole command which is going to be parsed by the shell on the Android device. The whole command always has to go into a separate argument as demonstrated above.

Comment: thanks..it worked 95% exact... saved the tussle.....! I just added single ' ' to make it work for me, in accordance to the question's sample...